# android animation translation with repeat mode

Tags: android-animation

How to do this type of animations [Animation](https://youtu.be/H7jdIAiVpsM?t=267)

time between 4:27 and 4:33
I'm a newbie, please suggest me how to do this ?
I tried with normal animation. But I couldn't do it. Anyone suggest me some better ways ?